# Trying to compare value of string that are programmatically added with javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to prevent my laps from counting the same second. So I'm trying to take the current value and evaluate it as != not equal to the previous value before appending it.

Here is the function, and my HTML. Not sure if I can do anything with the ids I set up. I have jquery set up to run in my javascript, so if you have any ideas with that I would be open to listening. There are a couple of things that probably don't have a use that I have not removed yet.

**Javascript Function**

```
let seconds = 0;
let minutes = null;
let hours = null;
let startTimer = null;
let time = null;
let isRunning = (false);

let lapContainer = [];
let x;
let outputseconds;
let outputminutes;
let outputhours;

//connection to button
document.getElementById("start").addEventListener("click", start);
document.getElementById("stop").addEventListener("click", stop);
document.getElementById("reset").addEventListener("click", reset);
document.getElementById("lap").addEventListener("click", lap);
document.getElementById("resetLaps").addEventListener("click", resetLaps);

//functions
function start() {
    if (isRunning === false) {
        isRunning = true;

        //interval
        startTimer = setInterval(function () {
            seconds++;

            if (seconds <= 9) {
                outputseconds = "0" + seconds;
                document.getElementById("seconds").innerHTML = outputseconds;
            } else if (seconds <= 60) {
                outputseconds = seconds;
                document.getElementById("seconds").innerHTML = outputseconds;
            } else if (seconds >= 60) {
                minutes++;
                outputseconds = "00";
                outputminutes = "0" + minutes;
                document.getElementById("seconds").innerHTML = outputseconds;
                document.getElementById("minutes").innerHTML = outputminutes;
                seconds = 0;
            } else if (minutes >= 9) {
                outputminutes = minutes;
                document.getElementById("minutes").innerHTML = outputminutes;
            } else if (minutes >= 60) {
                hours++;
                outputminutes = "00";
                outputhours = "0" + hours;
                document.getElementById("minutes").innerHTML = outputminutes;
                document.getElementById("hours").innerHTML = outputhours;
                minutes = 0;
            } else if (hours > 9) {
                outputhours = hours;
                document.getElementById("hours").innerHTML = outputhours;
            }
        }, 1000); //end of interval
    } // end of if check

    // should this be seperated out as a function???
    let startTime = "00";

    if (outputseconds > 0) {
        if (outputminutes > 0) {
            if (outputhours > 0) {
                return outputhours + ":" + outputminutes + ":" + outputseconds;
            } else {
                return startTime + ":" + outputminutes + ":" + outputseconds;
            } // hours
        } else {
            return startTime + ":" + startTime + ":" + outputseconds;
        } //minutes
    } else {
        return startTime + ":" + startTime + ":" + startTime;
    } // end of nested if seconds
} //end of start function

function stop() {
    clearInterval(startTimer);
    isRunning = false;
}

function reset() {
    clearInterval(startTimer);
    document.getElementById("seconds").innerHTML = "00";
    document.getElementById("minutes").innerHTML = "00";
    document.getElementById("hours").innerHTML = "00";

    seconds = 0;
    minutes = 0;
    hours = 0;

    isRunning = false;
}

function lap() {
    if (isRunning === true) {
        //initialize time
        let lapTime = start();
        //create connection to div
        lapContainer = document.getElementById("lapContainer");
        // how to check if they equal each other

        //create element
        const para = document.createElement("p");

        //how many laps have been created
        let i = document.getElementById("lapContainer").childElementCount;
        let index = [i];
        //create an index that will add an id to paragraph
        para.id = index;

        //add the lap to text
        para.innerText = lapTime;
        let laps = [];

        laps = document.getElementById("lapContainer").childNodes[1].textContent;

        let lastItem = laps[laps.length - 1];
        let currentItem = laps[laps.length];

        document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = laps;
        if (currentItem !== lastItem) {
            lapContainer.appendChild(para);
        }
    }
}

function resetLaps() {
    $(lapContainer).empty();
    isRunning = false;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />

        <title>Stopwatch</title>
        <meta name="description" content="A simple stopwatch application" />
        <meta name="author" content="****" />

        <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
        <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.svg" type="image/svg+xml" />
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="/apple-touch-icon.png" />

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/styles.css" />
    </head>

    <body>
        <!-- your content here... -->
        <div class="menu">
            <a href="timer.html" id="timer">Timer</a>
            <a href="alarm.html" id="alarm">Alarm</a>
        </div>
        <div class="stopwatch-container">
            <div class="stopwatch-wrapper">
                <div class="stopwatch-button-container">
                    <button type="button" id="start">START</button>
                    <button type="button" id="stop">STOP</button>
                    <button type="button" id="reset">RESET</button>
                    <button type="button" id="lap">LAP</button>
                    <button type="button" id="resetLaps">RESET LAPS</button>
                </div>

                <div class="rectangle-container">
                    <div class="rectangle">
                        <p id="textWrapper">
                            <span id="hours">00</span>:<span id="minutes">00</span>:<span
                                id="seconds"
                                >00</span
                            >
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="lineBreak"></div>
        <div id="lapContainer" class="lap-container"></div>
        <p id="test"></p>
        <script src="./scripts/scripts.js"></script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You don't need to call `Boolean()`, `true` and `false` are booleans, you don't have to convert them.

Comment: And you should just write `if (isRunning)`, you don't need `== True`

Comment: Your code is wrong. `laps` is a local variable and will thus be always empty if initialized. Also you access it using incorrect indices. Start counting at `0` and end at `length - 1`

Comment: I can make laps global. The isRunning = false makes sense, and the if(isRunning) makes sense. I'll make the changes.

Comment: I had a problem with a variable, so I made it global.  Then I had two problems.

Comment: Okay, when it runs the first time at the point of the check it has not appended anything to the  divyet. So it doesn't exist. It can't go past the first run, because it is undefined. Is there an easier way to check that the values do not equal each other from something that is added programmatically from a button? I can post my full code so you understand how i'm passing the values from the stopwatch.

Comment: This is not a good design to read variables *from* the dom.

Comment: I'm new to javascript. What would be a better way? I'm guessing you are talking about performance lags due to pulling from DOM?

Comment: No, not performance. It's about separating the code from its presentation. Use variables to hold the values instead of reading them from the "screen".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Few things you might need to do:

1.When you set the `laps` array you need to get the array of texts of the all nodes, not just a text of the first node:

```
//laps = document.getElementById("lapContainer").childNodes[1].textContent;
laps = Array.from(document.getElementById("lapContainer").childNodes).map(node => node.textContent);
```

2.When you set `currentItem` you can not use `laps[laps.length]` because your new value not in the array yet and so it will return `undefined`. Instead you can just use your `lapTime` value:

```
let lastItem = laps[laps.length - 1];
//let currentItem = laps[laps.length];
let currentItem = lapTime;
```

Example:

```js
let isRunning = Boolean(true);
let lapContainer = [];

document.querySelector('#lap').addEventListener('click', () => lap());

function lap() {
    if (isRunning === true) {
        //initialize time
        let lapTime = start();
        //create connection to div
        lapContainer = document.getElementById("lapContainer");
        // how to check if they equal each other

        //create element
        const para = document.createElement("p");

        //how many laps have been created
        let i = document.getElementById("lapContainer").childElementCount;
        let index = [i];
        //create an index that will add an id to paragraph
        para.id = index;

        //add the lap to text
        para.innerText = lapTime;
        let laps = [];

        //laps = document.getElementById("lapContainer").childNodes[1].textContent;
        laps = Array.from(document.getElementById("lapContainer").childNodes).map(node => node.textContent);

        let lastItem = laps[laps.length - 1];
        //let currentItem = laps[laps.length];
        let currentItem = lapTime;

        document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = laps;
        if (currentItem !== lastItem) {
            lapContainer.appendChild(para);
        }
    }
}

const start = () => new Date().toString();
```

```html
    <body>
        <!-- your content here... -->
        <div class="menu">
            <a href="timer.html" id="timer">Timer</a>
            <a href="alarm.html" id="alarm">Alarm</a>
        </div>
        <div class="stopwatch-container">
            <div class="stopwatch-wrapper">
                <div class="stopwatch-button-container">
                    <button type="button" id="start">START</button>
                    <button type="button" id="stop">STOP</button>
                    <button type="button" id="reset">RESET</button>
                    <button type="button" id="lap">LAP</button>
                    <button type="button" id="resetLaps">RESET LAPS</button>
                </div>

                <div class="rectangle-container">
                    <div class="rectangle">
                        <p id="textWrapper">
                            <span id="hours">00</span>:<span id="minutes">00</span>:<span
                                id="seconds"
                                >00</span
                            >
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="lineBreak"></div>
        <div id="lapContainer" class="lap-container"></div>
        <p id="test"></p>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </body>
```